# How to setup a webtorrent tracker

Tags: tracker, webtorrent

I am wondering why I can not find a webtorrent tracker, which is supported by `webtorrent-hybrid`. I just want to setup an own tracker like openwebtorrent-www, but i.e. this tracker has on github just html code (https://github.com/openwebtorrent/openwebtorrent-www). Do anyone know some open source webtorrent tracker (I mean not bittorrent).

Thank you!

//Allan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, the answer is very easy. Take a look at:  https://github.com/webtorrent/bittorrent-tracker

and install the webtorrent tracker global by: `npm install bittorrent-tracker -g`

Comment: I've updated the README: https://github.com/webtorrent/bittorrent-tracker#command-line

If you are using WebRTC torrents only, I would recommend uwt: https://github.com/DiegoRBaquero/uWebTorrentTracker#cli

Comment: This uWebTorrentTracker link is for an archived repository